# Convert Cookie string in DateTime value

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I need convert one Cookie string value in DateTime value in c#.

The cookie is valid because if try this:

```
Response.Write(Request.Cookies["dt"].Value + "<br />");
```

In output I have:

```
08/07/2015
```

I can't convert this Cookie string on DateTime.

I have tried this method:

```
DateTime DataCookie;    
DataCookie = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Cookies["dt"].Value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I have thie error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Wath's a wrong?

Comment: The format is dd/MM/yyyy not yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, your format and string doesn't *exactly* match.

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

Use `dd/MM/yyyy` format instead.

```
DataCookie = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Cookies["dt"].Value,
                                 "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```